# Why do I sometimes get itchy skin after taking a shower?

Tags: dermatology

I live in a hard water area, and I sometimes get very itchy skin (typically on my arms and legs) that feels like having tiny pin-pricks, after taking a shower. It lasts for ten minutes or so, then goes away. I don't use any shower gel, soap or shampoo, so its pure tap water. I'm male, and I have hairy arms and legs. Could it be the hairs reacting to the change in temperature?

Comment: The fact that it only happens *sometimes* means there's a variable (which could be anything). Try looking at all the variables: water temperature, water source (does it happen at the gym? after swimming?) the towel you use (fresh? What kind of fiber?), etc. etc. Eventually you'll narrow something down which will make this question easier to answer with facts.

Comment: I can rule out gym/swimming, and generally the water temperature is the same (warm and not too hot). The towel material could be a variable, as well as the detergent used to wash it, but again these don't vary. Drip-drying could be a useful experiment I suppose.

Comment: Could it be irritation because of showering (too) often?